# Problem reading numbers from file using stdin in C

Tags: c, stdin

I have to read in a stream of numbers from a text file into my code using stdin by passing my program the file like `./msort <segment count> <file.txt`.

I tried 2 methods of reading in the numbers, however these methods only work when I read them line by line as strings. I tried following a few links to type and typecast the string to an int, however I had no luck. The integer outputs are all just garbled. This is the code:

```
#define BUFFERSIZE 10

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <segment count>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    char *line = NULL;
    size_t size;
    while (getline(&line, &size, stdin) != -1) {
        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0;
        printf("%d\n", (int)*line);
    }

    // char *text = calloc(1, 1), buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
    // while (fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, stdin)) 
    // {
    //     text = realloc(text, strlen(text) + 1 + strlen(buffer));
    //     strcat(text, buffer);
    //     buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;
    //     printf("%d\n", (int)*buffer);
    // }

    return 0;
}
```

Could you please help me out with this?
[screenshot of code and text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjY7S.jpg)

Comment: `(int)*buffer` this is wrong, a cast doesn't do any conversion. You're looking for [`strtol`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/)

Comment: `(int)*buffer` -> `strtol(buffer, NULL, 10)`

Comment: Could you please share contents of the file you're using?

Comment: To read numbers from a character buffer, use `int n = sscanf(buffer, format, &result, ...)`. See your scanf manual page.

Comment: @RohanKumar its a file with 10 newline separated integers. NOTHING else

Comment: Read [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and **read *carefully* the documentation** of [scanf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html). Enable all warnings in your compiler. With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), read its documentation and compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger

Answer (score 1):

Use `strtol` to read numbers from strings:

```c
#include <errno.h> // errno
#include <stdlib.h> // strtol

// ...

    char *line = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;
    errno = 0; // Reset errno before calling strtol.
    char *endptr; // Used to check where strtol ended reading a number.
    while (getline(&line, &size, stdin) != -1) {
        long val = strtol(line, &endptr, 10); // Read a number from the line.
        // Double-check that a number was indeed read. If you don't want to errorcheck,
        // you can remove this, take out "#include <errno.h>", "errno = 0" and replace
        // &endptr with NULL.
        if (errno != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "strtol: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            return 1;
        } else if (endptr == line) {
            fprintf(stderr, "strtol: no digits were found\n");
            return 1;
        }

        printf("%d\n", val);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some problems with your code.

You want to read lines from file specified as command-line argument(`argv[1]`) but you're passing `stdin` as parameter. you should open the file using `fopen` and use that file pointer in `getline` method like shown below.

You can then use `sscanf` to read integer values from the line string.

```c
FILE *pFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if (!pFile) {
    printf("Error opening file %s\n", argv[1]);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

int currentNum;
while (getline(&line, &size, pFile) != -1) {
    line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0;
    sscanf(line, "%d", &currentNum);
    printf("%d\n", currentNum);
}
```